# First dayof the week - iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to count the data for each date of the week from a AWS. The first day of the week is set to monday. This causes my program to run inside a infinite loop. Can't seem to get it why.

```
-(void)weekSectionSorting{

NSCalendar* calendar    = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Singapore"]];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter  = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];       // Initialize NSDateFormatter.

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents* comps = [calendar components:NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit |NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];


[comps setWeekday:2]; // 2: monday
NSDateComponents* todayDc = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
NSDateComponents* oneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[oneDay setDay:1];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"dd-MM-yyyy"];


BOOL notToday = YES;
int count = 0;

NSDate *d = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
DLog(@"First day of week : %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:d]);
while (notToday) {
    count += [[self.dataDict objectForKey:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:d]] count];

    DLog(@"%i",count);
    NSDateComponents* curDc = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:d];

    if ([curDc year] == [todayDc year] && [curDc month] == [todayDc month] && [curDc day] == [todayDc day]) {
        notToday = NO;
    }

    d = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDay toDate:d options:0];
  }

}
```

Comment: //First day of week : 22-10-2012//    


this is the output. So i guess its calculating from the week that is yet to start that is tomorrow.